# Stable solution of nonlinear equation

Tags: numerical-methods, exponential-function

I'm trying to numerically solve equation for $t\in \mathbb{R}$
$$
n \cdot e^{At}x_0= c
$$
$A \in \mathbb{R^{3\times 3}},n,x_0 \in \mathbb{R^3}, c \in \mathbb{R}$. I'm looking for smallest positive solution. I have tried Newton's method but it doesn't work. Can you please recommend me a suitable method?

Comment: Hint: possibly a simplex method

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look.